# read PDF file as text using Python

Tags: python, pdf

Error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/XXX/pdf_to_text.py", line 7, in module
>       import slate
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\slate__init__.py", line 48, in 
>       from slate import PDF
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\slate\slate.py", line 3, in module
>
> from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser, PDFDocument
>
> ImportError: cannot import name PDFDocument

Code:

```
import slate
with open('C:\Users\XXX\XXX.pdf', 'rb') as f:
pdf_text = slate.PDF(f)
print pdf_text
```

Can someone advise on how to solve this error?

I will like to read a `.PDF` file text content using `Python`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the correct `pdfminer` version. Seems like the one you have does not define `PDFDocument` which is why you are getting the `ImportError`. Check for dependencies in `slate` and get the right version.

You can check existing version by doing

```
pip list
```